# How to find a cost of a query in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I ran an Athena query, it took 20 minutes to run and it scanned over 2 TB of data. Is it possible for me to find out the exact query cost in AWS itself? So not just the scan, but the complete:

```
sum = data_scan_cost + s3_cost(read) + s3_costs(write)
```

Comment: If you're not already, ensure you're compressing your data into a optimised format e.g. parquet or orc, otherwise your Athena costs are going to start adding up quite quickly. Compressed data = less scanning = less cost.

Answer (score 1):

Cost is $5 per TB scanned; so this would cost you ~$10 in athena queries.

Without understanding how much data you wrote out to s3 we can't get an accurate read of that, but at .023/GB I imagine this is negligible. Put and get requests cost money, but for the context of this single query they're negligible.

All in, around $15 considering your ~2TB scanned is closer to 2.5.

Comment: It's not entirely true that there are no S3 costs, most of the time they are negligible, but they do add up over time. You get charged for the number of LIST, GET, and PUT operations that Athena performs. At $0.005 for LIST and PUT, and $0.0004 per GET it's nothing when considering a single query, but if you are running a lot of queries it definitely adds up.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I've added some additional language.

Comment: `You get charged for the number of LIST, GET, and PUT operations that Athena performs`

Is this true? I have been searching and did not find any clarity on this on AWS site or anywhere else. If there are millions of small files and I use Athena, then it would drive costs up isn't it?

Comment: Yes Sarang, that's exactly what happens. It would be great if we could trace back all these costs to the query, but I'm not sure yet how.